# Как получить временную зону сервера или Москвы

Tags: время, javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Время намаза по КЧР</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var y_u_1 = new Date(<?php echo date("Y"); ?>, 11, 1, 06, 05); // дата события

        var initial_time = <?php echo time() * 1000; ?>;

        var intervalId = 0;

        var delay = 1000;

        function on() {

            setTimeout(f_y_u_1, 5000);

            function f_y_u_1() {

                var v, td, tsec, tmin, tj, tmr;

                v = y_u_1;
                td = new Date(initial_time);

                td = Math.floor((v - td) / 1000);
                tsec = td % 60;
                td = Math.floor(td / 60);
                if ( tsec < 10 ) {
                    tsec = '0' + tsec;
                }
                tmin = td % 60;
                td = Math.floor(td / 60);
                if ( tmin < 10 ) {
                    tmin = '0' + tmin;
                }
                tj = td % 24;
                td = Math.floor(td / 24);
                if ( td > 0 ) {
                    tmr = td + " дней " + tj + " чаc." + tmin + " мин." + tsec + " c.";
                }
                else {
                    if ( tj > 0 ) {
                        tmr = tj + " чаc. " + tmin + " мин." + tsec + " c.";
                    }
                    else {
                        if ( tmin > 0 ) {
                            tmr = tmin + " мин. " + tsec + " c.";
                        }
                        else {
                            if ( tsec > 0 ) {
                                tmr = tsec + " c.";
                            }
                            else {
                                f_y_u_1();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = tmr;

                initial_time += delay;

                if ( !intervalId ) {

                    intervalId = setInterval(f_y_u_1, delay);
                }
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-size:30px" align="">
    До события осталось: <br/> <br/>
    <span id="t"></span>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    on();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Руслан904322, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: это  код таймера, который работает на сайте. Так вот время он берет с сервера - но стоит клиенту изменить часовой пояс на своем пк - меняется и время (((

Comment: Из [википедии.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Московское_время)

Или из [javascript](http://javascript.ru/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Или из... Блин, [ну вот же, вот оно!](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%5B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D%20get%20timezone&clid=2192594&lr=213&suggest_reqid=69734261139532947011593533235960&csg=1211%2C17078%2C30%2C26%2C0%2C0%2C0)

Comment: я пытался вставлять date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow') - что я только не вписывал -  но таймер всегда зависим от временной зоны ПК((((((((((((((

Comment: а я хочу, чтобы всегда была временная зона Москвы

Comment: Вы б разобрались хоть, что такое time() и что она возвращает. Она возвращает timestamp, у которого нет временной зоны как таковой (хотя можно считать ее равной +0, насколько понимаю).

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();

// +3 hours 
d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() + 3);
alert(d.toUTCString());
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/m8b8L4L2/)

Либо используйте [TimezoneJS](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) или [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: это не правильный ответ - объясню на примере - запускаю твой код показывает время 21-00 но стоит мне изменить на компе временную зону у тебя уже часы перемещаются на несколько часов

Comment: @Руслан904322, часто ваши пользователи будут менять системное время на компьютере?

Comment: все может быть -  хочется, чтобы таймер был реально независим от времени пользователей

Comment: @Руслан904322 

> но стоит мне изменить на компе временную зону

Я всё правильно понял.

В моём примере данные возвращается в UTC+0, а в [UTC](http://goo.gl/cDCx44), как мы знаем, нет привязки к таймзоне.

Вы крутите время, а нужно выставить таймзону. Поставьте, к примеру, таймзону/часовой пояс Киева или Лондона.

P.S. У пользователей разные таймзоны. Они не время системное "выкручивают", а выставляют таймзону.

Comment: видимо нужно серверное время... ну так и передавайте его с сервера.